# Convert array to slice in Go

Tags: go

This seems like it would be a fairly common thing and abundant examples across the interwebs, but I can't seem to find an example of how to convert an `[32]byte` to `[]byte`.

I have a function that I call from an external lib that returns an array

```
func Foo() [32]byte {...}
```

I then need to pass that result to a different function for further processing.

```
func Bar(b []byte) { ... }
```

Unforunately, if I try to call

```
d := Foo()
Bar(d)
```

I get

```
cannot convert d (type [32]byte) to type []byte
```

Doing

```
[]byte(d)
```

isn't much better.  How do I do this, especially without creating a copy of the data (seems silly to copy this data when all I'm doing is passing it along).

Comment: See https://blog.golang.org/slices

Answer (score 148, accepted):

This should work:

```
func Foo() [32]byte {
    return [32]byte{'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}
}

func Bar(b []byte) {
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}

func main() {
    x := Foo()
    Bar(x[:])
}
```

And it doesn't create a copy of the underlying buffer

Comment: is it possible to get a oneliner like `Bar(Foo()[:])` working?

Comment: @BluBb_mADe no. A slice is basically a struct under the [covers](https://blog.golang.org/slices) with underlying references to: a buffer; its length; and its capacity. To initialize a slice's buffer - one needs addressable memory from the _heap_ not the _stack_ (where return values are stored) - as stack memory is not persistent outside of its function.  It's the same reason one can't do something like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/edY6tPPlqeM).

Comment: oh well, why do these things always have to be so logical.

Answer (score 107):

```
arr[:]  // arr is an array; arr[:] is the slice of all elements
```

Answer (score 12):

This will do the trick:

```
slice := array[0:len(array)]
```

Also avoids copying the underlying buffer.

Comment: The default for the lower bound is 0. The default for the upper bound is `len(x)` so `x[0:len(x)]` is better written as `x[:]`. Which is exactly what the existing answer says.

Comment: I find the number of downvotes a little harsh considering the validity of the solution...

Comment: Although the OP just wanted a full conversion of the underlying array, it's useful to know that specifying lower bound and upper bound is identical to slice annotation.  For example, you might want to allocate an array (instead of use make slice) then set portions of the array using lower bound/upper bound notation.

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/BwIvavioBj

Answer (score 10):

You can generally slice an array by its bounds with `:` :

```
var a [32]byte 
slice := a[:]
```

More generally, for the following array :

```
var my_array [LENGTH]TYPE
```

You can produce the slice of different sizes by writing :

```
my_array[START_SLICE:END_SLICE]
```

Omitting `START_SLICE` if it equals to the low bound and `END_SLICE` if equals to the high bound, in your case :

```
a[0:32]
```

Produces the slice of the underlying array and is equivalent to :

```
a[0:]
a[:32]
a[:]
```

Answer (score -1):

Say, if you have an existing array my_array, create a new slice and append array to it

```
var s []string
s = append(s, my_array...)
```