# Function should return sha256/sha384/sha512 result as byte slice

Tags: arrays, go, cryptography

I'm writing a function that takes input data as a string and the bit size of the SHA algorithm to be called. It should return the resulting hash as a byte slice (first attempt):

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "crypto/sha512"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    input := "This is a test."
    sha256, _ := shaSum(input, 256)
    sha384, _ := shaSum(input, 384)
    sha512, _ := shaSum(input, 512)
    fmt.Println(input, sha256, sha384, sha512)
}

func shaSum(data string, size uint) ([]byte, error) {
    input := []byte(data)
    switch size {
    case 256:
        return sha256.Sum256(input), nil
    case 384:
        return sha512.Sum384(input), nil
    case 512:
        return sha512.Sum512(input), nil
    default:
        return nil, errors.New("unsupported sha size")
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, of course:

```
$ go run shasum.go
# command-line-arguments
./shasum.go:22:23: cannot use sha256.Sum256(input) (type [32]byte) as type []byte in return argument
./shasum.go:24:23: cannot use sha512.Sum384(input) (type [48]byte) as type []byte in return argument
./shasum.go:26:23: cannot use sha512.Sum512(input) (type [64]byte) as type []byte in return argument
```

So I'm trying to get a slice from the hash function's return value instead, adding `[:]` after each call (second attempt):

```
func shaSum(data string, size uint) ([]byte, error) {
    input := []byte(data)
    switch size {
    case 256:
        return sha256.Sum256(input)[:], nil
    case 384:
        return sha512.Sum384(input)[:], nil
    case 512:
        return sha512.Sum512(input)[:], nil
    default:
        return nil, errors.New("unsupported sha size")
    }
}
```

This doesn't work either:

```
$ go run shasum.go
# command-line-arguments
./shasum.go:22:30: invalid operation sha256.Sum256(input)[:] (slice of unaddressable value)
./shasum.go:24:30: invalid operation sha512.Sum384(input)[:] (slice of unaddressable value)
./shasum.go:26:30: invalid operation sha512.Sum512(input)[:] (slice of unaddressable value)
```

So I'm trying to get the address of the return value, using parentheses to ensure that the address of the expression is taken first and then sliced (third attempt):

```
func shaSum(data string, size uint) ([]byte, error) {
    input := []byte(data)
    switch size {
    case 256:
        return (&(sha256.Sum256(input)))[:], nil
    case 384:
        return (&(sha512.Sum384(input)))[:], nil
    case 512:
        return (&(sha512.Sum512(input)))[:], nil
    default:
        return nil, errors.New("unsupported sha size")
    }
}
```

Which yields this error message:

```
$ go run shasum.go
# command-line-arguments
./shasum.go:22:10: cannot take the address of sha256.Sum256(input)
./shasum.go:24:10: cannot take the address of sha512.Sum384(input)
./shasum.go:26:10: cannot take the address of sha512.Sum512(input)
```

So I'm giving up and solve it using extra lines (fourth attempt):

```
func shaSum(data string, size uint) ([]byte, error) {
    input := []byte(data)
    switch size {
    case 256:
        bytes := sha256.Sum256(input)
        return bytes[:], nil
    case 384:
        bytes := sha512.Sum384(input)
        return bytes[:], nil
    case 512:
        bytes := sha512.Sum512(input)
        return bytes[:], nil
    default:
        return nil, errors.New("unsupported sha size")
    }
}
```

Which finally compiles and runs. Now I'm wondering: why does the fourth attempt work and the others (especially the third attempt) don't? And how would a nice solution look like? Is there a way to avoid those additional lines like in the fourth attempt?

**EDIT**: The underlying problem of my question is not how to cast from a byte array to a byte slice, but my lack of understanding of the addressability notion, and on how to express the solution to my problem in idiomatic Go.

Comment: The "nice solution" is the final solution. The others don't work for exactly the reasons given in the error message - slices and bytes aren't interchangeable, and you can't take a slice of an unaddressable value like a function return value; you have to put it in an addressable value, i.e. a variable.

Comment: So the secret is not getting the address from the return value, but to store the result in the function context? EDIT: Is it not about the syntax but about memory management?

Comment: Not exactly. Slicing an array requires getting a reference (address) to the array internally.

Comment: @Adrian: This is what I tried to do in the third attempt. Is the syntax wrong  or is there just no syntax for doing what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: No, that's not at all what you're trying to do in the third attempt. It doesn't work because you're still trying to take the address of a return value, which you can't, and you don't need to slice a pointer to an array - the *slice operation itself* has to be able to address the array *internally*. A slice is just a *pointer to an array* and start/end indices.

Comment: That's what I _wanted_ to do, which seems to be impossible technically. So is it important to _store_ the return value so that I can slice it? What's the underlying difference? I see that there _is_ a difference between attempt three and four, I just don't understand _why_ this is the case.

Comment: Yes, you have to store the value before you can slice it or get a pointer to it. Until you store it, there is no address to get.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162374/discussion-between-patrick-bucher-and-adrian).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert array to slice in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886616/convert-array-to-slice-in-go)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language specification [states this about the slice operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions):

> If the sliced operand is an array, it must be addressable and the result of the slice operation is a slice with the same element type as the array.

and [this about addressability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators):

> The operand must be addressable, that is, either a variable, pointer indirection, or slice indexing operation; or a field selector of an addressable struct operand; or an array indexing operation of an addressable array.

It follows from this that the fourth attempt is the only one that works.

Here's an alternative approach using the  [hash.Hash](https://godoc.org/hash) interface.

```
var hashFactory = map[int]func() hash.Hash{
    256: sha256.New,
    384: sha512.New384,
    512: sha512.New,
}

func shaSum(data string, size int) ([]byte, error) {
    f := hashFactory[size]
    if f == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("unsupported sha size")
    }
    h := f()
    io.WriteString(h, data)
    return h.Sum(nil), nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Importantly, note that the signature for the [`sha256.Sum256` function](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha256/#Sum256) (and the other SHA functions) returns an *array*, which is a different type entirely from a *slice*. This article explains the difference clearly: [Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals).

To illustrate, consider the following:

```
x := [3]int{1, 2, 3} // x has type [3]int
y := []int(x) // ERROR: cannot convert x (type [3]int) to type []int
```

Here's why each of your attempts does not work:

1. The `shaSum` function returns a tuple of `([]byte, error)` but each return statement attempts to return `([Size]byte, error)`, so the compiler complains about the mismatched types.
2. Each `sha*.Sum*` function returns a `([Size]byte, error)` tuple; you cannot use the `[:]` operator on a such a tuple, only on [arrays and slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions).
3. Similar to #2 above, you can only use the `&` operator on [addressable types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators), which does not include function calls (or the values they return, until they are stored locally).
4. This working example is idiomatic go. The language designers deliberately chose to optimize for clarity to readers rather than shorthand for writers.