# can not write to file

Tags: arrays, go

I tried to code a OneTimePad with go but I cant write to file:
The files are bin files (compiled Go code) 
My Code:

```golang
package main
import ("fmt"
       "io/ioutil"
        "math/rand")

func rndByte(l int)[]byte{


    token := make([]byte, l)
    rand.Read(token)
    return token
}

func writeByteFile(filename string,inp []byte ){

    err := ioutil.WriteFile(filename, inp, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

func readFile(filename string) []byte {
        data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("File reading error", err)

        }

        return data
}



func main(){
    x := readFile("xor")
  //  y:= len(x)
    z := rndByte(489)

    var res [489]byte
    for i:=0; i != 489; i++{
        res[i] = x[i] ^ z[i]
    } 
    writeByteFile("xorKey", z)
    writeByteFile("xorENC", res)
}
```

**my Error:**

# command-line-arguments
./xorbyte.go:47:19: cannot use res (type [489]byte) as type []byte in argument to writeByteFile

Comment: Arrays and slices are covered in the Tour: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/6. I'd suggest taking the full tour to get a grasp of the language fundamentals. It only takes a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

`[489]byte` and `[]byte` are different types.

`[489]byte` is an array

`[]byte` is a slice

try to convert array to slice:

```
writeByteFile("xorENC", res[:])
```

Checkout https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Answer (score 1):

Here you are doing wrong conversion from byte array to byte slice. To convert an array to a slice you can use the following syntax:

```golang
var byteArray [5]byte
byteSlice := byteArray[:]
```

Ref: [Convert array to slice in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886616/convert-array-to-slice-in-go)

So, you can try this way,

```golang
writeByteFile("xorENC", res[:])
```